# IFrame Image Resizing

Tags: html, iframe, compatibility

In any modern browser, when you visit an image url (eg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCjwv.jpg), it automatically resizes that image and gives you the option to "zoom in" with a little magnifying glass. This is not always the case with an iframe:

```
<iframe src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCjwv.jpg'> </iframe>
```

If you link an iframe to an image, Firefox will give this nice behavior: it starts out behaving like `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%`, then you can click on it to make it big.

However, in Chrome, the image is just full-size. Try opening [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/TXSKy/) in Chrome and Firefox.

How do I get Chrome to handle images "smartly"? That is to say, have the default behavior show a magnifying glass cursor and provide auto-resizing?

(To clarify: I want this to work in a Chrome extension. The only solution I've come up with so far is to put a content script on all pages and manually change styling on images on the page. That solution sucks, so I'm hoping for a method that is less hacky and doesn't effect every page the user visits)

Comment: You may find that this is a design choice of the browser.  I don't expect to get that kind of zoom functionality unless the image is the only thing loaded into the browser - FireFox seems to have added this as a "bonus" feature.

Comment: Even if it is a design choice, I'm still looking for a workaround to get "better" image behavior from my iframes.

Comment: I don't think there is a more reasonable way to do it than what Joelio described in his answer. That, or using a server-side script to download the image, resize it and place the resized version on the site. Then, you can bind a click handler to the image, which will display it in full size and then the resized version on second click. You can even use CSS to add a nice cursor when hovering over the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the iframe refer to another html file and in that html file put the img tag with the width and height constraint. I think it will work on most browsers this way.

Comment: I'll try adding to an html.